# Creating a login page with powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I am just trying a few things with powerapps and I created a simple login page. The excel sheet with username and password info is stored on OneDrive. I wrote a small code for when login button is selected but I always get "Incorrect login details." What am I doing wrong here?
here is my code for onselect event

If(UserName.Text in Table1.USERNAME && Password.Text in Table1.PASSWORD, Navigate(Dashboard,None),Notify("Incorrect Login Details",NotificationType.Error));

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are using in to compare the login values with those saved in excel, if any record in a username column matches another record in the password column then it is validated and it should not be like this.

Here is an exampple.

```
UpdateContext(
    {
        found: LookUp(
            users,
            username = txtUsername.Text
        )
    }
);
If(
    found.username = txtUsername.Text && found.password = txtPassword.Text,
    Navigate(
        Screen1,
        Fade
    ),
    Notify(
        "Wrong authentication",
        NotificationType.Error
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You likely do not want to manage usernames and passwords and store them in something like OneDrive. Your users have already authenticated to Active Directory in order to access PowerApps.

Just store their email addresses and user type in the Excel sheet:

| Email | UserType |
| --- | --- |
| Bob@Bob.com | Admin |
| Sam@Bob.com | User |

**Then try:**

- `OnStart` of the App control:

```
Set(varUserEmail, User().Email);
Set(varUserType, LookUp(Table1, Email = varUserEmail, UserType));
Switch(varUserType,
    "Admin", Navigate(scrDashboard, Fade),
    "User", Navigate(scrWherever, Fade),
    Notify("Incorrect Login Details", NotificationType.Error)
)
```

**Note:** You will need to keep `Table1` in sync with all the users your app is shared with (not maintainable for large user base).

- For a scalable solution, consider using the `Azure AD` connector and determining if the user is part of a Security Group to control navigation.

  - Then you just create an AD Security Group(s)
  - Share the PowerApp with said Group(s)
  - And as users are added/removed from Group(s), there's only one source of truth

Comment: Thank you, yes I wasn't going to use excel was just trying to learn powerapps.